# Collapse multiple columns in responsive table with CSS

Tags: css, responsive, css-tables

Does anyone ever had a solution for such kind of problem?
Let's say we have a table:

```
ID       Year      X      Y
---------------------------------
1,       2000,     3,     4
1,       2001,     5,     6
```

and want to collapse single column when the window is resized, so that the last column jumps to as a sub row like this:

```
ID       Year      X      
----------------------
1,       2000,     3,     
  Y   4
1,       2001,     5,   
  Y   6
```

at next resizing we get:

```
ID       Year          
-----------------
1,       2000,         
  Y   4
  X   3
1,       2001,       
  Y   6
  X   5
```

Comment: This is probably only possible if you hardcode the table header in the CSS.

Comment: can we do some JS trick?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be too hard. Detect when the columns are past the right-hand side and add them as a subtable in a new merged row added beneath the original, or something.

Comment: If only we could use html tags in css content..

Comment: That would be too OP for a style sheet.

Comment: will try to write some simple js for this and post it here as it is very valuable for mobile responsiveness and cannot find any reasonable source for this.., don't want to use jQuery

Comment: try this - https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/full/wXgJww/, i hope this is what u are looking for

Comment: @Girish thanks for reply, but that's one single column collapse and what we are trying to achieve here is multiple column collapse to use space more effectivelly

Comment: @m4ngl3r, why don't you give a try based on that example, and create multiple breakpoints